# Rewriting Url's .Net 3.5 Web.config - Redirecting

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

When i have the following structure:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="ggdwb" stopProcessing="true" enabled="true">
        <match url="(.*)" /> 
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(www.)?websitename.nl" /> 
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/$" /> 
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="" redirectType="Temporary" />
    </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

How can I make sure that for example "http://www.websitename.nl/foldername" will redirect to
http://exampledomain.com/client/1/?websiteid=1&contentid=1 ?

Comment: What's happening with the rule you already have? Also are you using the IIS 7 reqrite module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a rule to your  section. Each rule must have a unique name.

```
<add name="Rule1" 
virtualUrl="~/foldername" 
destinationUrl="~/client/1/?websiteid=1&contentid=1" 
ignoreCase="true"/>
```